# Console.ReadLine() on Mono sometimes doesn't display the first few input characters

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I have this piece of code which reads and displays input strings until a `hello` is entered.

```
string x;
do
{
    x = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine ("{0}\n",x);
}
while (x != "hello");
```

Here is a sample run:
[image]
Here, as soon as the External Console appeared, I typed `test` first. But only `est` appeared. But as can be seen, the value is read correctly and `test` was written out. When I typed `hello`, it displayed `ello`, but read `hello` and terminated the loop.

I haven't been able to pinpoint exactly when this occurs, but some of the times its because I would have typed the input string a little too quickly. Sometimes it displays quickly typed input without any problem. In the above screenshot, I typed `test` at normal speed.

Is this a bug or is this a dependency issue?

PS: I have `xterm` installed; I am on CrunchBang Linux, which is Debian based; Mono runtime is `2.6.7-5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug with the way the window system renders characters from the standard input on your platform. I wouldn't be concerned as long as the string you get contains all the text.

I don't think Mono is to blame here. I might have suspected Mono if it happened only during initial load - but since you state it happens at different times, I'm thinking it's probably something peculiar with the OS.